# Use NSPredicate to filter entries that start with non-alphabetic character

Tags: ios, uitableview, nspredicate

I have a UITableView that I am trying to split into sections A-Z and then # for everything else, I am trying to filter out the data from my main array into the non-alphabetic section with:

```
NSArray *selectionArray = [nameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF beginswith[c] %@)", @"^[A-Za-z].*"]];
```

Unfortunately it is not working how I thought it would and everything is being put into `selectionArray`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like "beginswith" operator does not support regular expressions. The next predicate worked for me "NOT (SELF MATCHES[c] '^[A-Za-z].*')".